# how can I go from groggy to kotlin Dsl protobuf

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am applying Proto DataStore and I am applying protobuf in my Kotlin Dsl gradle but I can't implement it correctly. enter the code here.

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id ("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.12"
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0"
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thank you very much!.

Answer (score 0):

**So I could adjust it in Gradle in kotlin**

```
plugins {
    id ("com.google.protobuf") version ("0.8.12")
}
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = if (osdetector.os == "osx") {
            ("com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0:osx-x86_64")
        } else {
            ("com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.14.0")
        }
    }
   generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach {
            it.builtins {
                create("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In this way configure the gradle for proto DataStore**